# Run mapslices in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I use `mapslices()` to apply the same expression for each row of some array:

```
function f(x)
      ...
end

a = rand(Normal(), 10000, 50)

b = mapslices(x -> f(x), a, dims = [2])
```

Is there some elegant way to run a similar procedure in parallel using all the CPU cores? Something similar to how in R you can replace `apply()` with `future_apply()`, so that everything is automatically parallelized. Or `mapslices()` are not suitable here at all and is needed to use some other structure?

Comment: Not built-in. https://github.com/mcabbott/SliceMap.jl has `ThreadMapCols` and (apparently not in the docs) `tmapcols`. You might also look at https://github.com/tkf/ThreadsX.jl whose `map` you can probably apply to `eachcol(x)`

Answer (score 1):

You could write this usin `@distributed` loop.

Consider the code

```
using Distributed
addprocs(4)
a=collect(reshape(1:12,3,4))
```

And now:

```
julia> @distributed (vcat) for col in 1:size(a,2)
           sum(@view(a[:,col]))+1000*myid()
       end
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2006
 3015
 4024
 5033
```

It can be seen that the first column was summed using the first process, second using the second process etc.

Depending on the scenario you might consider using also `SharedArrays` for storing the data.
Finally you might also have a look at `pmap` and `preduce` in the `Distributed` package. Depending on the scenario they might be a good fit.